# changing input type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, input

I currently have an input with a button type but i wanted to change how the button looks to match the rest of my web page buttons but i am having problems:

This input works like it should but doesn't show the image i want it to show for the button:

```
<input type="button" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Content/images/newCancel.png")%>" onclick="goBack()"/>
```

This shows the image but doesn't function like it should - it doesn't execute the javascript:

```
<input type="image" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Content/images/newCancel.png")%>" onclick="goBack()"/>
```

Any help will be great

Comment: I have never seen this sort of syntax used before <%: what version did they introduced it last i knew we could use it this way <%@

Comment: @HatSoft: He's using a depracated version of the ViewEngine. You definitely want to use the `@` symbol for most use cases. `<%:Url.Content...` is the same as `@Url.Content...`.

Comment: @SergioTapia thank you, now it make sense why i did not knew that style of syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An input with a type of image submits the form.  Put a "return false;" at the end of the onclick and it should prevent the form's submit.

```
<input type="image" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Content/images/newCancel.png")%>" onclick="goBack(); return false;"/>
```

Alternatively, you could just create the image and add the event directly to the image.

```
<img src="<%:Url.Content("...")%>" onclick="goBack();" />
```

Comment: Setting too much Javascript inside an event handler is a code smell in my opinion.

Comment: How about adding a return at the end of goback() and then using a onclick="return goBack();"?  I agree with your premise, but I hardly think a "return false" is any worse than a onclick event anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
<input type="button" onclick="goBack()"/>
```

And using CSS:

```
input[type='button'] {
    background: url('../Content/images/newCancel.png') no-repeat;
}
```

If you want to use embedded styles or inline styles, you can have access to the `@Url.Content()` method, but I'd advise against it.